# My roblox script keeps getting a DataStoreService error in output

Tags: lua, roblox

Me and my friend are making a game where it saves how many studs a player has travelled and puts it on a global leaderboard. the scripts work but i keep getting this error:

```
  22:02:11.734  DataStoreService: SetAsyncThrottle: SetAsync request dropped. Request was throttled, but throttled request queue was full. API: SetAsync, Data Store: Distance  -  Server
  22:02:11.734  302: SetAsync request dropped. Request was throttled, but throttled request queue was full.
    Stack Begin
    Script 'ServerScriptService.Datastore', Line 28
    Stack End  -  Server
```

Me and my friend are not very experienced in coding and we learn by using code tutorials and changing them to match the game and give us the outcome we want. The problem is probably that there is to much data to store because of how quickly the distance changes overtime since it counts everyone stud. Ive tried to fix the problem by changing the cooldown time in the datastore and leaderboard script but it either doesnt work or gives the same error. Ive added both scripts below and im hoping to learn how to solve this issue for the future

The datastore script is below:

```
local DSS = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DS = DSS:GetDataStore("Distance")

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local data

    local success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
        data = DS:GetAsync(plr.UserId)
    end)

    if success then
        if data then
            -- Set the leaderstats.Distance.Value based on stored data
            plr.leaderstats.Distance.Value = data[1]
        else
            print("Player joined for the first time.")
        end
    elseif errorMsg then
        warn(errorMsg)
    end

    -- Update leaderboard with the player's current distance
    plr.leaderstats.Distance:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function()
        local currentDistance = plr.leaderstats.Distance.Value
        local storedDistance = DS:GetAsync(plr.UserId)

        if storedDistance and currentDistance > storedDistance[1] then
            DS:SetAsync(plr.UserId, {currentDistance})
        end
    end)
end)

game:GetService("Players").PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    local data = {
        plr.leaderstats.Distance.Value
    }

    DS:SetAsync(plr.UserId, data)
end)
```

Global leaderboard script:

```
local ODS = DSS:GetOrderedDataStore("Distance")

local stat = script.Parent.Stats
local Template = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("Template")

local cooldown = 60 * 2

local function updateBoard()
    local data = ODS:GetSortedAsync(false, 10)
    local page = data:GetCurrentPage()

    for i, v in ipairs(page) do
        local name = game:GetService("Players"):GetNameFromUserIdAsync(v.key)
        local studs = v.value
        local rank = i
        local onBoard = false

        for i, v in pairs(stat:GetChildren()) do
            if v:IsA("UIListLayout") then continue end

            if v.Name == name then
                onBoard = true
                local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(name)
                if player then
                    local currentDistance = player.leaderstats.Distance.Value
                    if studs > currentDistance then
                        -- Only update if the stored value is higher
                        v.studs.Text = studs
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        if not onBoard then
            local temp = Template:Clone()
            temp.Name = name
            temp.user.Text = name
            temp.rank.Text = rank
            temp.studs.Text = studs
            temp.Parent = stat
        end
    end
end

while true do
    for i, v in ipairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()) do
        local currentDistance = v.leaderstats.Distance.Value
        local storedDistance = ODS:GetAsync(v.UserId)

        if storedDistance and currentDistance > storedDistance then
            ODS:SetAsync(v.UserId, currentDistance)
        end
    end

    for i, v in pairs(stat:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("UIListLayout") then continue end

        v:Destroy()
    end

    updateBoard()
    wait(cooldown)
end
```

ive tried changing the code slightly to reduce the requests by adding cooldowns but it hasnt worked, the purpose of these scripts is just to display the highest amount of studs a player has travelled and to put that information onto a global leaderboard

Comment: You are getting throttled, which means that you are making too many requests to update your datastores. Rather than update the store whenever the value changes, consider updating on a fixed timer, or whenever the player leaves the game.